# Text not getting to the console

Tags: c#, stdout

I have a c# project of type "console" it starts into it's own app domain from within a parent app, and it spawns a console window. However any text written to the console doesn't show up. `Console.ReadKey()` does work however. Any ideas what could be wrong ?

Note: Echo's to the parent process are showing in the parent process' embedded console (which isn't a win32 console but a directx GUI widget of some sort) `Console.Out` and `System.Console.Out` are not a "null" stream.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

using ParentApi;

namespace LSTest4
{   
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.OpenStandardOutput();
            ParentApi.Echo(System.Console.Out.ToString());
            Console.Out.WriteLine("monkeys");
            Console.WriteLine("app start");
            Console.Write("lalala");
            Console.ReadKey();
            ParentApi.Echo("app start");

    }
}
```

**edit:**

Upon further investigation:

The code in question is injected into another application, the injection is hostile and is managed by the "ParentApi", and it seems injection target is remapping the standard streams. In this case the best thing to do is to have the tracing handled in some other way. I might use WCF to push out the tracing output to an external process.

Comment: Try `StreamWriter standardOutput = new StreamWriter(Console.OpenStandardOutput());
        standardOutput.AutoFlush = true;
        Console.SetOut(standardOutput);`

Comment: What happens if you *don't* use `Console.OpenStandardOutput();`?

Comment: @SLaks nope, didn't do it.

Comment: Can you post enough sample code from the parent project so that we can reproduce this?  Or alternatively, create a new parent project which just tries to reproduce this and post that.

Comment: @Bobson Hmm, the parent project is closed source, and the problem seems to be with it since running the app from within visual studio does work. Though the snipit posted by Slaks above should fix things :/

Comment: I'd keep pursuing what SLaks commented, because your child console doesn't appear to be the standard output. Is there something in the ParentApi namespace that can redirect output?

Comment: @glace - I suspect that the `directx GUI widget of some sort` is to blame.

Comment: @Bobson text doesn't get to that console, only when I go via `ParentApi.Echo()` does text get there. I'm thinking the stdout goes to some log file. I'm chasing up the developer on IRC. still slaks' snippet should fix that.

Comment: The developer just told me he doesn't touch `stdout` or any other default stream, and that it should work out correctly with what I am trying to do. I don't think it's a project config issue since the app, launched from VS, works fine.

Comment: @HassanSyed - My best suggestion is to create an entirely new project which consists of nothing but the console control and a button to launch this program.  See if you can reproduce the behavior in that minimalist scenario.  If not, then it's something in your code.

Comment: "The code in question is injected into another application" - you might have mentioned that up front. Also I assume you mean WCF, not WPF?

Answer (score 2):

I think your issue is going to be something about the parent app; you mention that the parent doesn't display the real Win32 Console, which is where I imagine the child `Console.WriteLine` calls are going.
I did a little POC (happy to share the code), which showed that a parent can redirect Console output using `Console.SetOut`, but a different AppDomain call to `Console.WriteLine` is still going to the main console instead of the new stream.

Further, the underlying Win32 API states that a `process can be associated with only one console`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681944%28VS.85).aspx

If you really need a child Console, you might have to spin off a new process and use interprocess communication.

**Edit**
Disproving myself slightly, changing my parent app from Console to Windows (so that it's still runnable) meant that my child AppDomain could print to the Console it defined, and my parent could still write to the redirected stream. Although, this would still only allow one child; as above.
Maybe if you could provide the code on how you spawned your AppDomain it would help?